CUDA: Nth set bit indexes using all threads in a warp in O(1) time
I have a 32-bit bit mask holding a set of valid items.
From that bit mask I want to extract the indices of valid entries as a list.
Let's say I obtained the bit mask using a ballot, and I want to know the ids of the valid threads as a sequential list, e.g.:
const auto bitmask = __ballot_sync(-1u, isValid);
if (threadIdx.x == 0) { printf("Bitmask = $%x\n); } 

For example, if the mask is 0b100010001 I want to extract three items
0, 4, 8.
How do I extract the bit indices of set bits in an int32 using all threads in a warp in constant time (no loops)?

A streamlined version of CudaaduC's forum post works in a few instructions:
auto lanemask_lt() {
  uint32_t result;
  asm ("mov.u32 %0, %%lanemask_lt;" : "=r"(result));
  //or: -1u >> (32 - (threadIdx.x % 32));
  return result
}

auto lanemask_eq() {
  uint32_t result;
  asm ("mov.u32 %0, %%lanemask_eq;" : "=r"(result));
  //or: return 1 << (threadIdx.x % 32);
  return result
}

The lanemasks are intrinsic instructions that read special gpu registers.
These are combined with a popcount to get the position.
void PrintValidIndices() {
  assert(threadIdx.x < 32);
  const auto isValid = ((threadIdx.x % 3) == 0);
  __shared__ int ValidIndex[32];
  ValidIndex[threadIdx.x] = -1;
  const auto Mask = __ballot_sync(-1u, isValid);
  const auto pos = __popc(Mask & lanemask_lt());
  //use if you don't have an isValid flag from before
  //const auto isValid = (Mask & lanemask_eq()); 
  //__syncwarp(); not needed because ballot already synced ValidIndex[]
  if (isValid) { ValidIndex[pos] = threadIdx.x; }
  __syncwarp();   
  printf("ValidIndex[%i] = %i\n", threadIdx.x, ValidIndex[threadIdx.x]);
}

The way this works is as follows:
Input : 32 booleans -> bitmask
IsValid every 3th lane gives bit mask : ...001001001001001
The lanemask_lt() is 0 for lane 0 and 1111 for lane4, i.e. as many 1's as there are lanes before the current thread.
lanemask_eq() is 1 for lane 0 and 10000 for lane4, i.e. the bit matching that lane is set.
finally, __popc counts the number of set bits in a mask, this is used to extract the index, like so:
For lane 0 the result is always 0, it is valid, index[0] = 0.
lanes 1,2 are not valid
For Lane 3 the result is valid
...00000111 &   (lanemask_lt(3))         
...01001001     and (Mask)
-----------     =
...00000001 =>  1 bits set, index[1] = 3.

For Lane 9 the result is valid
..00111111111 &   (lanemask_le(9))         
..01001001001     and (Mask)
-------------     =
0000001001001 =>  3 bits set, index[3] = 9.

Invalid lanes do not get written
Only valid indexes get written, and so in our example every third index is put into the list:
output: [0, 3, 6, 9, ..., 30, -1, -1, ...]


Since CUDA 12.5 you can also use cuda::ptx::lanemask_lt() etc. from CCCL/libcu++.
